# How to save dynamically created views on Fragment replace?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment used as a form where I **dynamically** populate it with `EditText` and `Checkbox` views on the method `onCreateView`. I want to be able to save their state whether there is another fragment on top of that one:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(fragment.getTagText())
        .commit();
```

And erase those children view `onBackPressed` when that fragment is pop out of the stack. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could just do it manually by saving the fields' contents in a custom object and populate the form when fragment is on foreground again

Comment: @kimimsc Yes, I think that might be the best solution... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To save put your state in `Bandle`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And restore from `Bandle` in:

```
public void onCreateView(ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

or

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

or

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: But that is just useful to retrieve basic information data right? Like String, int... Not an actual list of views created dynamically? Because what I wanted initially what to retrieve the same populated views that I had before

Comment: Save a list of the data on which is built dynamic views. Save list like `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.